# Fetching actionPerformed from another class

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that implements actionPerfomed and gives a certain functionality to buttons. In the same class I have a constructor that when called I want it to "fetch" the actionPerformed that lives in another class and gives a different functionality to my buttons.

The code in my constructor looks like this:

```
    button1.addActionListener(new MyButtonActionListener());
```

where `new MyButtonActionListener()` contains the the actionPerformed that I want to call. Problem is that nothing happens when I click on the button. 
I am just playing around and don't know if this can even be done. Thanks!

```
public class ButtonFrameActionListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private MyButton button1 = new MyButton();
    private MyButton button2 = new MyButton();
    private MyButton[] buttons;

    public ButtonFrameActionListener(){
        super("A button window");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

        myPanel.add(button1);
        myPanel.add(button2);

        button1.addActionListener(new MyButtonActionListener());
        button2.addActionListener(new MyButtonActionListener());

        buttons = new MyButton[2];
        buttons[0] = button1;
        buttons[1] = button2;

        this.add(myPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    for(int i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++){
        if(e.getSource() != buttons[i]){
            buttons[i].toggleState();
        }
    }
}
```

//****************************************************************************//

```
public class MyButtonActionListener extends MyButton implements ActionListener {

    public MyButtonActionListener(Color col1, Color col2, String text1, String text2){
        super(col1, col2, text1, text2);
        /**
         * listens for an action to be performed from actionPerformed.
         * does not come into play before the button is clicked.
         */
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public MyButtonActionListener(){
        this(Color.red, Color.yellow, "Press me", "Do it again!");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        this.toggleState();
    }
}
```

//********************************************************//

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
private Color col1;
private Color col2;
private String text1;
private String text2;
Boolean pressed = false;

public MyButton(Color col1, Color col2, String text1, String text2){
    this.col1 = col1;
    this.col2 = col2;
    this.text1 = text1;
    this.text2 = text2;
    this.setText(text1); // states the text for the initial state
    this.setBackground(col1); // states the color for the initial state
}

public MyButton(){
    this(Color.red, Color.yellow, "Press me", "Do it again!");
}

/**
 * decide the state of the button
 */
public void toggleState(){
    pressed = !pressed; // pressed equals true
    if(!pressed){ // if pressed equals false
        this.setText(text1);
        this.setBackground(col1);
    } else {
        this.setText(text2);
        this.setBackground(col2);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: nothing happens means probably you didn't doing anything in your actionPerformed method, could you share how you implemented it?

Comment: @BOND I will update now :)

Comment: Preferably post a [mcve].

Comment: @DoubleOseven what is MyButton, why does MyButtonActionListener needs to extend MyButton? As suggested by Hovercraft, please update your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense that `MyButtonActionListener` extends `MyButton`. Therefore `this.toggleState();` doesn't call `toggleState()` on the button on which the listener was added, but directly on the `MyButtonActionListener` instance (since it is a `MyButton`). Change

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    this.toggleState();
}
```

to

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ((MyButton) e.getSource()).toggleState();
}
```

and it will work. (Preferably also don't extend `MyButton` in the class)

Comment: thanks. I extend MyButton ActionListener in order to avoid writing (repeating) some of code again that is in MyButton. Is it to be avoided?

Comment: @DoubleOseven You don't need to repeat/extend code of the `MyButton` class in the `MyButtonActionListener` class. It's just a listener, and it all works fine with just the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method in it.

Comment: @DoubleOseven: that's mis-using inheritance. Inheritance doesn't work that way (as you're finding out), and should only be used for parent-child relationships. An ActionListener is not a specialized type of button, and so should not extend it.